# Adding days to calendar not working on Android

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
public void createWeeks(JSONArray TargetDays){
    int helper, targetDayPos, curDayPos;
    JSONArray dateContainer = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray dateData = new JSONArray();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    Utilities dayConverter = new Utilities(getApplicationContext());

    for(int i=0 ; i<TargetDays.length() ; i++){
        try {
            targetDayPos = dayConverter.getDayPosition(TargetDays.getString(i));
            curDayPos = dayConverter.getCalenderDayPosition(dayOfWeek);
            if (curDayPos > targetDayPos) {
                helper = curDayPos - targetDayPos;
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, -helper);
            }
            else if(targetDayPos > curDayPos){
                helper =  targetDayPos - curDayPos;
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, helper);
            }

            dateData.put(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            dateData.put(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
            dateData.put(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),curDayPos+"\n"+targetDayPos,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dateContainer.put(dateData);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        weekDayList.put("days",TargetDays);
        weekDayList.put("dates", dateContainer);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

i'm creating an array of days in a week and their date here. but adding days doesn't work and at the end i'm just getting date of today.

Comment: Could you make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please? I’m sure it would greatly help (us and you).

Comment: i need help about "add" method of calendar. it's not doing any thing. nothing happens. after i add days with it, and then i get time it's still the same date before adding. @Ole V.V.

Comment: I have quite great confidence in `Calendar.add()`. I suspect your problem is somewhere else. Did you try a debugger?

Comment: Since you need help, I suggest you help us help you. MCVE, please, but I am repeating myself.

Comment: When I say I have great confidence in `Calendar.add()`, I should mention that it is old stuff as of Java 8, and I would certainly consider using some of the new classes in the `java.time` package instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem and as @Ole V.V. said in the comment it wasn't about calendar.
the problem was about its algorithm. it was about the way i was creating the json array.

i changed it to this and handled it in a different way in my program:

```
    public void createWeeks(JSONArray TargetDays){
    int helper, targetDayPos, curDayPos;
    JSONArray dateContainer = new JSONArray();
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    Utilities dayConverter = new Utilities(getApplicationContext());

    try {
        for(int i=0 ; i<TargetDays.length() ; i++){

            c.setTime(currentDate);
            targetDayPos = dayConverter.getDayPosition(TargetDays.getString(i));
            curDayPos = dayConverter.getCalenderDayPosition(dayOfWeek);
            if (curDayPos > targetDayPos) {
                helper = curDayPos - targetDayPos;
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, -helper);
            }
            else if(targetDayPos > curDayPos) {
                helper = targetDayPos - curDayPos;
                c.add(Calendar.DATE, helper);
            }
            dateContainer.put(dateFormat.format(c));

        }
        weekDayList.put("days",TargetDays);
        weekDayList.put("dates", dateContainer);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```